# NSFetchRequest executeFetchRequest - worth including error parameter in this case?

Tags: ios, nsfetchrequest, nserror

Each time I write a method using an `NSFetchRequest` I faithfully include some version of the following boilerplate code:

```
NSError * error = nil;
NSArray * result = [context executeFetchRequest: fetchRequest error: &error];
if (!result && error) {
    NSLog(@"Error fetching - %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```

However, I can't remember having ever seen `executeFetchRequest` fail and have `error`  populated.

Certainly `executeFetchRequest`can fail (trying to create invalid SQL, say) but this raises an exception, rather than returning an error.

So, my question is this: **is it worth checking** `error` **each time, or would I be better to save myself the time and just write:**

```
NSArray * result = [context executeFetchRequest: fetchRequest error: NULL];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always worth including it.

showing the error to an enduser is useless
BUT logging it is ALWAYS good as it may potentially help you to better locate & fix a bug

Comment: Yes, I understand that they're not *required* - I'm just trying to figure out if it's worth my time including in this case - as I don't think I've ever seen it happen - it just fails with an exception.

Comment: I have that, 2nd sentence. rewrite your question title though

Comment: Write a method - (NSArray*)executeFetchRequest: and call it instead of the original method. In that method, you can add error logging, and you can set a breakpoint on the error case. That way you are notified of errors during development, and at least the error is logged otherwise. Obviously, if you run into a situation where you have an actual error, you either fix the code so you don't get an error, or you add error handling, because now you know it is actually needed.

Comment: I think the best thing to do here is to crash actually. There is not much you can do about error and higher level code can have trouble if you return empty array in case of error. We had this issue and ended up with corrupted data.

Comment: I agree that during development you wanna crash. In Production i'd not be so sure. We dont know what kind of data is being fetched... maybe the app can compensate for it missing or if it gets an error there it loads some online resource. ==> I would not always blindly crash